# What's wrong with this nginx.conf?

Tags: nginx

I'm using nginx as a load balancer to 4 internal server instances. The below nginx.conf will work correctly only for www.mydomain.com . But not for mydomain.com or http://mydomain.com.

```
upstream mydomain{
  server 127.0.0.1:8000;
  server 127.0.0.1:8001;
  server 127.0.0.1:8002;
  server 127.0.0.1:8003;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.mydomain.com;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://mydomain;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's normal that it doesn't work for `mydomain.com` because of `server_name www.mydomain.com`.

I'm not an nginx expert, but try omitting server_name.

Comment: post your full ngninx config, and tell us what do you mean by "only works". What happens on the other domain? Also, what happens if you change www.mydomain.com for mydomain.com, does mydomain.com start working?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.mydomain.com mydoamin.com;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://mydomain;
  }
}
```

At least I've found this solution in [docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html)

Answer (score 0):

all webservers will only work for the domain you configure. In this case, the only domain you added is www.mydomain.com, so it is only going to "work" for the address www.mydomain.com.

If you want all subdomain to work, you need a wildcard character in front of mydomain.com as the following:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name .mydomain.com;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://mydomain;
  }
}
```

Notice the . before mydomain.com.